# $http DELETE turns into OPTIONS AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest, express

When I use put or delete, it turns into OPTIONS. I am using expressjs for my server framework.

Client:

```
$http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: HTTP_URL + '/update/account',
    params: { mail: mail }
});
```

Server:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser is automatically sending the CORS pre-flight OPTIONS request; this is correct behavior and you can't avoid it.  If  the server allows the origin, method, etc., then the browser will follow up with the DELETE request.

Comment: then what should I modify in Origin, that this will work

Comment: I assume that you mean the browser not sending the DELETE request.  What specific headers are being sent to the server in the OPTIONS request, and what specific headers are being sent back by the server in the OPTIONS response?  With that information it should be evident what the problem is.  You may want to use a tool like Fiddler to monitor the request/response.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it normal for a preflight HTTP OPTIONS request to be made for CORS?  You may need to allow OPTIONS in your list of Access-Control-Allow-Methods...

Comment: Could you please clarify what errors are you getting? As @natwallbank said browser makes preflight HTTP OPTIONS request to ask about permissions to make an actual request. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: This happens if you are making "not-so-simple request" - DELETE is one of that kind of requests.

Comment: I did allow OPTIONS into my Access-Control-Allow-Methods, the same thing happen.

Comment: I don't have app.options('users/update'), because I have app.delete('users/update')

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use $resource instead of $http. It will save you some boilerplate, so:

```
var appServices = angular.module('appServices', [
  'ngResource'
]);

appServices.factory('Account', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/accountUpdate/:accountMail', {accountMail: '@accountMail});
}]);
```

and after that you can inject your Account service and make DELETE request, like so:

```
Account.remove({accountMail: 'admin@admin.com'});
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource